# using tuple with visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have an older code which uses:

```
#include <tuple>
```

This project is visual studio 2008 project. According to Microsoft, it is possible to to use Tuple with 2008 see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982837(v=vs.90).aspx) .
However, I cannot compile and I am getting this error:

> Error 34  fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tuple': No such
>   file or directory

Comment: check comment on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982198%28v=vs.90%29.aspx - maybe you need to install this Feature pack for VS2008 to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What works for me is installing service pack 1 from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10986)